# How to generate a color without using System.Drawing

Tags: c#, colors, system.drawing, system.drawing.color

I just want to know if there's any way to create a color, given a RGB, without importing `System.Drawing`. I want to use this color to fill some rectangles I have created.

Comment: What does it mean to "generate a color" or "create a color"?

Comment: Given a RGB, I want to create that color

Comment: The RGB *is* a color. What do you want to do with that color?

Comment: I want to fill some rectangles with it

Answer (score 3):

You mean you would like a color struct that will store for you r g and b values and helps you to convert it to a 32 bit integer?

```
public struct MyColor
{
    public int Value;

    public MyColor(int a, int r, int g, int b)
    {
        this.Value = ((a & 0xFF) << 24) | ((r & 0xFF) << 16) | ((g & 0xFF) << 8) | (b & 0xFF);
    }

    public MyColor(int r, int g, int b) :
        this(255, r, g, b)
    {
    }

    public int A
    {
        get
        {
            return (byte) (this.Value >> 24);
        }
        set
        {
            this.Value = (this.Value & ~(0xFF << 24)) | ((value & 0xFF) << 24);
        }
    }

    public int R
    {
        get
        {
            return (byte) (this.Value >> 16);
        }
        set
        {
            this.Value = (this.Value & ~(0xFF << 16)) | ((value & 0xFF) << 16);
        }
    }

    public int G
    {
        get
        {
            return (byte) (this.Value >> 8);
        }
        set
        {
            this.Value = (this.Value & ~(0xFF << 8)) | ((value & 0xFF) << 8);
        }
    }

    public int B
    {
        get
        {
            return (byte) (this.Value);
        }
        set
        {
            this.Value = (this.Value & ~(0xFF)) | ((value & 0xFF));
        }
    }
}
```

Note: just written by hand, there may be errors.